# Is there a way to append sorted dataframes and maintain sortedness by specific column?

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, group-by

I'm running into an issue working with this huge csv file (100M rows x 14 cols).

Essentially, there is one column `'MMSI'` that contains a unique identifier and I want to group the dataframe together by this column. I want to aggregate all the other columns to lists, so essentially my groupby result is almost the same size in memory as the original dataframe, which causes memory error every time. Eventually, I want to take each group of rows for each unique `'MMSI'` and do some stuff with them.

I had an idea to sort the dataframe, then I could find where the values change and loop over slices of the dataframe like this:

```
df = pd.read_csv(file)
df = df.sort_values(by='MMSI') #memory error
breaks = np.nonzero((df['MMSI'].diff() > 0).values)
```

and this

```
df = pd.read_csv(file)
df.sort_values(by='MMSI', inplace=True) #memory error
breaks = np.nonzero((df['MMSI'].diff() > 0).values)
```

so I had the idea to read the file in chunks and sort the chunks, then append the chunks together as I go, and try to maintain the sortedness. Currently the only way I could see doing this is:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame()
for chunk in pd.read_csv(file, chunksize=chunksize):
    chunk.sort_values(by='MMSI', inplace=True)
    df1 = df1.append(chunk, ignore_index=True).sort_values(by='MMSI', inplace=True)
```

which obviously just gets slower and slower...

I tried doing:

```
sorted(range(len(df)), key=df['MMSI'].__getitem__)
```

and:

```
df = df[df['MMSI'].argsort()] #memory error
```

to get the sorted indexes and:

```
mmsis = df['MMSI'].unique()
df1 = df[df['MMSI']==mmsis[0]] #memory error
```

and a few other spin off approaches all of which are giving me memory error or taking forever..maybe I just don't have enough patience

is there a faster way to sort a huge dataframe or append an already sorted dataframe to another and maintain the sort?

I'm open to other approaches.. I need to separate the data by MMSI somehow and memory is a huge issue

Comment: Couldn't you just collect all unique MMSIs as keys in a dictionary, and then iterate over the dictionary, applying whatever function you need to the current MMSI?

Comment: Work on the column first? `df.iloc[df["MMSI"].sort_values().index]`?

Comment: Both of those require masking the entire array which creates a copy and throws memory error

Comment: @patrick I need to group the entire csv/df by the MMSI, not just get the MMSIs... if I loop over them that means I have to mask the entire dataframe for every MMSI and I get memory error

Comment: @HenryYik tried tha ttoo, memory error because its a huge copy